# Regex to individuate entries separate by specific character

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm using Google Sheets and attempting to individuate the entries separated by [char10] >

Sample content from a cell:

> > low confidence registrar [char10]
> > No SSL certificate [char10]
> > Malicious intent [char10]
> > Complete sentence #4 [char10]

Closest I got so far was using the following Regex:

> "> (.*?) !"

which only yields the first entry.

How do I fix my regex to yield the many groups and separate them into different columns?

> Example: REGEXEXTRACT(H15:H,"> (.*?) !")

Comment: Please can you try `=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(CHAR(10)&H15:H,CHAR(10)&">")))` and see if you can avoid regex as `SPLIT()` looks like a better option?

Comment: Only way to do this would be to use regex twice. Obviously split is a much better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(H15:H, "> ", ), CHAR(10)))
```

[image]